# Pre calculating aggregate functions performance improvementation when using Aggregate Functions

Tags: java, mysql

When I am writing aggregate functions like SUM,SUB,MAX in mySQL query it is taking more time when for the data is gathering from multiple tales for performing aggregate functions.

Is there any way to pre calculate those aggregate functions and use it in my query for better performence? For example:

```
  select sum(t1.col1),sum(t2.col1)
  from tab1 join on tab2
```

Comment: Which database/language are you talking about? Of course there is many way to pre-compute and cache these values. Too many to mention here.

Comment: Please show your query and choose the right database.  Depending on the circumstances, the answer to your question is yes, no, maybe.

Comment: I am using MySql Db and Java Language(Spring,Hibernate).